# Calculate $P(0)$ knowing condition that polynomial satisfies.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Polynomial $P(x)$ is of degree $n$ and it satisfies:

$P(k)=\frac1{k}$ for $k=1,2,4,...,2^n$

Calculate $P(0)$.

---

$P(x)=a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$

$0=k\times P(k)-1=a_nk^n+...+a_0=a_n(x-1)(x-2)...(x-k)$

$-1=0 \times P(0)-1=a_n\times-1\times-2\times...\times-k=a_n\times(-1)^{n+1}\times2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

$a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$

Comment: Hint:   Let $Q(x)=xP(x)$.  Then $Q$ has degree $n+1$ and we know $n+2$ values, so $Q$ is determined uniquely.

Comment: @lulu So would it be good to build system of equations? $Q(0)=0,Q(1)=1,...,Q(k)=1,Q(2k)=1$

Comment: Well, it's probably a lot easier to note that $Q(x)-1$ has $n+1$ known roots.  Thus we know what $Q(x)-1$ is up to a multiplicative constant.  And then you also know the value at $x=0$ which lets you determine that constant.

Comment: I guess i do not follow

Comment: $Q(x)-1$ vanishes at $2^a$ for $a\in \{0, \cdots, n\}$.  Thus $Q(x)-1=\lambda\times \prod_{a=0}^n(x-2^a)$ for some constant $\lambda$.  But $Q(0)=0$ so we can solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: Isnt it exactly what I've done?

Comment: Perhaps, I had trouble following what you wrote.  Why should $0=kP(k)-1=a_n(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-k)$?  Aside from the fact that $0$ is not a function of $x$ (and neither is $kP(k)-1$), $k$ is not a root of $xP(x)-1$.

Comment: So what information does that constanst give us?

Comment: If we know that constant then we know $Q(x)$, hence we know $P(x)$.

Comment: Could you please give full answer?

Comment: I prefer not to write out full answers to problems like this.  you have a relatively simple expression for $xP(x)$.  One way to proceed is to take derivatives to get a relatively simple expression for $P(x)+xP'(x)$.  Now just set $x=0$.

Comment: This question is from early high school contest, so no mathematical analysis. Either way, I do not how knowing $a_n$ imply knowing $f(0)$

Comment: Well, the derivative gives a quick way to do it.  Otherwise...well, you know $xP(x)$ so all you want is the coefficient of $x$ in that product.  Same thing, really, but you never have to mention the derivative.

Comment: @lulu Very elegant.  It took me a few minutes to wrap my brain around what you 
did.  I request that you transplant your notes into a Hint-Answer, which is where
I think this analysis belongs.  I suggest that you totally avoid any Calculus
concepts and just focus on manually identifying the constant $k$, where
the constant (i.e. $x^0$) term of $k \times \left[\prod_{i=0}^n (x - 2^i)\right]$ must equal $-1$, since
the constant term of $\{[x \times p(x)] - 1\}$ is $-1.$  ...see next comment

Comment: @lulu As a hint, you
might also mention that in order to solve the problem, one can ignore all **other**
coefficients except $a_0$.  Also, I recommend that you don't spell things out
more than you already have, since this problem may be from an active contest.
**No way** would this be a standard problem on any high school homework or test
(at least not in America).

Comment: This problem is not from active contest. https://om.mimuw.edu.pl/static/app_main/problems/om48_1.pdf Sixth problem in that link (1996)

Comment: I checked by hand few low degree polynomials and my guess is that answer is $1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$, also i belive that way of solving that is by using Viete’a formula for second coefficient in $Q(x)$, but i do not know how to calculate such sum

Comment: @1qwertyyyy  Yes!  But that is just a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20series,previous%20term%20by%201%2F2.).  Closed formulas for the sum are known, even in high school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the rather lengthy discussion in the comments:

First define $Q(x)=xP(x)$.  We know, of course, that $$Q(k)=1\quad \text{for}\quad k\in\{1, 2, 4,\cdots, 2^n\}$$

Since $Q(x)-1$ has degree $n+1$ and we have $n+1$ zeroes we have $$Q(x)-1=\lambda\prod_{i=0}^n(x-2^i)$$
for some constant $\lambda$.  We can compute $\lambda$ by noting that $Q(0)=0$ so $$-1=\lambda\prod_{i=0}^n(-2^i)\implies \lambda=\frac {(-1)^n}{\prod_{i=0}^n2^i}$$

So we know $Q(x)$ explicitly, hence we know $P(x)$.  To compute $P(0)$ we remark that $P(0)$ is the coefficient of $x$ in $Q(x)=xP(x)$. This quickly returns $$\boxed{P(0)= \left(1+\frac 12 + \frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{2^n}\right)= \left(2-\frac 1{2^n}\right)}$$ where, at the last stage, we have used the standard method for evaluating Geometric Series.

Note:  I suggest checking the arithmetic here.  In particular, check the signs. This is the sort of problem for which it is annoyingly easy to drop or add a sign.